# autologon fails on some windows 7 systems

Tags: windows-7, windows-domain, auto-login

Hi I'm having some weird problem with the windows autologin on a couple of Windows 7 Systems.
Suddenly after months of working correctly it fails to login on some systems. (not all of them)
It just gives you a user or password not correct fault while they are correctly entered in the registry. When you remove the error it shows you .\username instead of domain\username.

Removing the autologon makes it boots directly to the login as other user button. Anybody had this problem before or any hints how to fix it.

Comment: Found a solution. on the defaultUsername registry key add the domain to the username. expl: domain\username. This fixed the not login in, but I didn't find a reason why.

Answer (score 0):

Tetting, you can take a look at [LogonExpert](http://www.logonexpert.com/learnmore.html) software, yes it is paid peace of soft but it worth it